# Context menu rename any file as "folder.jpg"

Tags: context-menu, regedit

Simply put i want to make a context menu entry that renames an image file as "folder.jpg"

When i view folders in the thumbnail view mode, the folders will show a thumbnail image of the file or image they contain, if i put a .jpg inside and rename it to folder.jpg, the folder will choose that image for the thumbnail

This is a nice way for me to organize my folders, sometimes renaming the folder isn't enough if i have to many.

I'm naming by hand the prefered image, I renamed hundreds of images by now but it would be great if I can have a context menu option to rename the photo as "folder.jpg"

I tried to make a reg key but I don't know how, I tried this from different sources:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\rename to folder.jpg]
@="Rename-Item <folder.jpg>"
```

but it's giving me an error:

```
This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Apps Settings page.
```

Comment: Alternate way: make batch script to rename input file, place in Send To folder.

Comment: So please spell out exactly what this thing does. (in your question, not a comment)  If I understand correctly (which I doubt), you want to right click a .jpg or .png.. or "whatever" and have the file renamed to match the name of the directory it is in?

Comment: hi, i edited the question, sorry english is not my native tongue

Comment: Your command is not valid PowerShell. But in the first place, the command needs to be an executable, for example `powershell.exe`.

Comment: I would like to make it as a registey key

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your comment. The context menu entry you are going to add (using the registry) must point at an executable.

Comment: i see, i thought it might be possible to ad a function to change the file name